# MySQL update a column by selecting from 2 other columns every second time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table 'game' that contains these 4 columns:

id: id of this game row

user1: user id of 1st player

user2: user id of 2nd player

active: id of the player who can make draws.

Can I make a single UPDATE that sets 'active' to the value stored in 'user1' and then next time I make the UPDATE, it sets 'active' to the value stored in 'user2' and so on?

I have tried this, but it doesn't work.

`UPDATE game SET active = (IF active = (SELECT user1 FROM game), (SELECT user2 FROM game), (SELECT user1 FROM game)) WHERE id = '$idSql';`

Comment: You could improve your question by explaining what "doesn't work" means (e.g., wrong row updated, computer exploded, etc.)

Comment: lol. Well, my computer survived.
But good point. I will keep that in mind next time (this was my first question on Stack Overflow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE game
SET active = IF (active = user1,user2,user1)
WHERE id = '$idSql';
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you wanted

```
UPDATE game SET active = IF (active = user1,user2,user1) WHERE id = '$idSql';
```